# GWT: Identify which Button in a Table was clicked

Tags: button, gwt

I am struggling with something which I think should be extremely easy.

I have a Grid in GWT, which I populate its cells with some textual data; at the last column I want to place a Button (or Image) which when clicked, I would like to take some action using the specific/associated data for that row.

I want to use a single ClickHandler for all the buttons. How can I then identify which button (and subsequently which row) has been clicked? Can I associate some sort of tag/identity value to a button (or Image) widget in GWT? With this identity/tag value, then I would be able to identify which row data I am working with.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

In the handler use method `getCellForEvent(ClickEvent event)` of your `Grid` object. It will return `HTMLTable.Cell` object which has both row and column index. You pass the event object that has been delivered to the handler method. It works even if you have embed widgets in the cell and you get the click event for that widget.

Actually the method is defined in base `HTMLTable`, so you can use it also in `FlexTable`.